# How to reverse the elements stored in an unknown size array in C#?

Tags: c#

how can i reverse the elements stored in an unknown size array. i have used the List myList = new List(); to be able to store unknown number of elements but i want to display the elements stored in reverse order. i have used

```
foreach(string listItem in myList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(listItem);
            }
```

but it wasn't displaying in reverse order.Is there a method i can use in order to do that?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as an unknown size `Array` (or `List`). The `.Length` (or `.Size`) will give you the number of items.

Comment: Do you know how to create an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`Enumerable.Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358497%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method

```
foreach(string listItem in myList.Reverse())
```

Note that it doesn't modify the list. It returns elements in reversed order *lazily*.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

```
        for (int i = myList.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myList[i]);
        }
```